# CSS selector is not working using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

instructions for the project is to 
create a simple web page application that allows the user to enter one or more stock ticker symbols and
display price information about these stocks.
• Data has to come from a REST API (https://www.alphavantage.co), it is free to use and returns JSON
formatted output.

Here is my code so far and I'm not being able to figure it out
UPDATED 
when a user types a symbol, it's not showing anything on the console. how can I make it that for every symbol a user inputs , it fetches the price from the url and gives price.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#searchstock').on('click', function() {

    let requestData = $('search').val();
    let resultElement = $('stock');
    // Make request to rest API
    $.ajax({

      url: 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES&symbols=' + requestData + '&apikey=SB1CZMKQ6Q5283QZ',
      method: 'get',
      data: {
        symbols: requestData
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        resultElement.html('price:' + data.Stock_Quotes[0])
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Stocks</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="https://bootswatch.com/4/simplex/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="searchContainer">
      <h1>Enter symbol</h1>
      <p class="lead">Enter a a symbol to fetch a price </p>
      <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Stock symbol...">
    </div>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="searchstock" class="btn btn-info">Get price</button>
    <br>
    <div id="stock"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- script src="js/main.js"></script -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Okey then what actually is your question/issue ?

Comment: "not being able to figure it out" - figure *what* out?  What is happening vs. what is expected behavior?

Comment: it's not working so do you see any nugs that I don't? Or do you have a different/better approach to do this?

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: Please don't edit your question to remove the actual question. That is deemed to be "vandalism". Also, please don't edit the code to "fix" it as the answers could then make no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You expected this line to match the input having its id attribute set to "search":

```
let requestData = $('search').val();
```

jQuery select function requires a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors) as its first argument. Now in your code, the CSS selector you give to `$` function is`'search'` and this actually means *«Please match elements having their name being "search"»* and not *«Match elements having their id attribute set to "search"»*.
Do you see the difference ?

Simply change `$('search').val();` to `$('#search').val();` as `#` tells to match the "id" attribute.

The same goes for this line.

```
let resultElement = $('stock');
```

---

**You also have a property name issue**.
Querying for "MSFT" will return something like:

```
{
  // …
  "Stock Quotes": [
    {
      "1. symbol": "MSFT",
      "2. price": "93.0300",
      "3. volume": "--",
      "4. timestamp": "2018-03-02 15:59:59"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the data object property is called "Stock Quotes" and not `Stock_Quotes` as you put it in your code.

As the property name contains space, square brackets notation is required to access this entry. Retrieving the price for the first result will look like this:

`resultElement.html('price:' + data["Stock Quotes"][0]["2. price"])`

Comment: @ryan I have edited my answer. This is trivial debugging and a dive into documentations will help you feel more comfortable with the issues spotted here. If your issue is fixed, please mind setting your question as resolved by ticking the answer that helped you the most. Oh! I'm the only answer!

Comment: @ryan What I suggested you to change will make your code work. 1 - Replace id attributes `'search'` → `'#search'`, `'stock'` → `'#stock'`, 2 - Replace the line `resultElement.html(…)` with `resultElement.html('price:' + data["Stock Quotes"][0]["2. price"])`. 3 - Re-run your snippet, fill in the input with "MSFT" and voilà. 4 - Tick the answer.

Comment: First, now that your initial issue is solved, you should mark it as resolved by ticking my answer.

Comment: `"Stock Quotes"` is an array of objects. So all you have to do is using the [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). On each iteration you can create a `<tr>` element in a table for exemple.

Comment: Here is [a quick working exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/anng61cs/). Fill the text field with `MSFT,FB`

Comment: Put this under your pellow  [Mozilla development Network > JavaScript section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference). Read books like [this one](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) or [this one](http://www.google.fr/search?q=javascript+the+good+parts)

Comment: The funny thing is that `$(search)` would actually work, as would `$(stock)`. So few people know that.

Answer (score -1):

Try making use of oninput instead of onclick if you want to execute search/ajax-call whenever a user types a symbol.

```js
$('#search').on('input', function(e) {
  var resultElement = $('#stock'),
    requestData = $(this).val();

  // Make request to rest API
  $.ajax({

    url: 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES&symbols=' + requestData + '&apikey=SB1CZMKQ6Q5283QZ',
    method: 'get',
    data: {
      symbols: requestData
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      resultElement.html('price:' + data["Stock Quotes"][0]["2. price"])
    }
  });
});
```